# Laravel загрузка данных при открытии modal

Tags: bootstrap, laravel

Имеется таблица. При нажатии на строку открывается модальное окно. При открытии идет обращение к модели. Собственно таблицу и открытие сделал, но как обратиться к контроллеру в момент открытия не понятно.

Comment: когда должно происходить образение к модели? сразу при открытии окна? или при сабмите формы? что именно должно происходить с моделбю? оттуда данные берутся, или записываются?

Comment: Сразу при открытии окна. Обращаемся к контроллеру, он обращается к модели, получает данные из таблицы БД - возвращает в modal-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте ajax при открытии окна.

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
        var url = 'Ваш путь к контроллеру, который выдаст вам данные из модели';
        $.ajax({
            url: url, 
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){  
            // Тут делаете что нужно, с полученной информацией
           }
        });
    });
```

Comment: И как в таком случае передать параметры? В url-е?
app.product.show/?id=$id

Comment: data { id: 1, is_crab: 'no' }, добавьте параметр data =)

Comment: если бы я видел код, можно было бы что-то более детальное предложить

Comment: Да нет, думаю отработает такой вариант как надо, просто я думал laravel какую-нить свинью подбросит) Может и пример маршрута привести? Если не сложно)

Comment: вы в web.php вписываете к примеру Route::get('/dashboard/list', 'AppsController@list'); где в контроллере AppsController есть экшн с названием list , там же и путь - /dashboard/list. Вот этот путь и нужно вписывать, а если вы передаете только id, есть смысл сделать контроллер типа Route::get('/dashboard/list/{id}', 'AppsController@listsome'); и передавать /dashboard/list/ВАШ_ID, по крайней мере я так делаю))